# unable to identify element in selenium with firefox security warning

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing problem with `.click()` method in Firefox browser because of Firefox security message.

In my login form, I have one username and password field and submit button. After successfully entering a username in Firefox, the browser shows security message:

> "This connection is not secure.Logins entered here could be
>   compromised.Learn more"

and instead of selecting (clicking) password field it clicks on this security message and new Firefox browser tab gets open instead of entering password value.
How can I handle such situation?

I have Firefox version 55 and Selenium version 3.5.2

Comment: Use DesiredCapablities class to solve ur issue

Comment: Try my code once may be it helps u ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set capabilities to disable that security message

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: :- Thanks for your code but i am not asking for SSL certificate security concern, i am asking for the security message  "This connection is not secure.Logins entered here could be compromised.Learn more" that appears in firefox 55 when we entered any username/password. i hope u understand.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: :- I tried the code given by you but i am facing same problem.:(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `DesiredCapabilities` class to set capabity which enabled **SSL certificate** and then you are easy to locate your element. Please find below code to do so:

```
DesiredCapabilities ffCapablity = new DesiredCapabilities();
ffCapablity.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E://FF//geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ffCapablity);
```

Second way to solve this problem, then you have to refer following link:

[How to Solve SSL ERROR](https://www.guru99.com/ssl-certificate-error-handling-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the URL with which you are a working is `Not Secure` then whenever you try to access the URL through Mozilla Firefox 55.x, Firefox will display a lock icon with red strike-through icon in the address bar. Now when URL gets loaded the cursor by default will be positioned on Username field and there will be popup showing a message `This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised` as [documented here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/insecure-password-warning-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct).

In these cases the best solution is:

1. Create a new Mozilla Firefox Profile. You will find the [documentation here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). For Example, I have created a Firefox Profile by the name `debanjan`
2. Configure the Firefox Profile `debanjan` to ignore all the `UntrustedCertificate` issues.
3. Rerun your Test Script without any issues.
4. Here is a sample code block to disable `insecure_field_warning`:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
   ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
   testprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
   testprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
   testprofile.setPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);
   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
   dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
   WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.navigate().to("http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php");
   ```